# How to fire ManipulationStarted on multiple UIElement with the same touch?

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I have a Grid with 4 UIElement. I've subscribed the event ManipulationStarted and ManipulationCompleted on all the elements.

On ManipulationStarted I change the color of the element and on ManipulationCompleted I set it back to the original one.

This works, but only for one item, if I tap on an item and then, without leaving my finger, i move to another one, it does not change color.

To make it clearer:

[image: This is the normal situation]

This is what I see when I open the app. 4 UIElements (Rectangle) in a Grid.

[image: This is what happens when I press on an element]

This is what I see when I hold the finger on a Rectangle.

[image: This is what I want to happen]

This is what I want to happen when I hold the finger on a rectangle and then I move the finger on another one without lifting the finger, but it doesn't happen. It just works on one rectangle.

This is the code of the events that are on every rectangle:

```
private void Rectangle_ManipulationStarted(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    if(sender is Rectangle)
        ((Rectangle)sender).Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Purple);
}

private void Rectangle_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    if (sender is Rectangle)
        ((Rectangle)sender).Fill = originalColor;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to make the interaction be something like if you hold on one rectangle, and move your finger to another rectangle, than the rectangle you move your finger to turns the same color as the rectangle your movement originated from?

Comment: It's more like you have a default color (purple, in my case) that should be set to every rectangle that you touch while you move your finger. When you release your finger they get their original color back.

Comment: Whew, that's a broad one, could only speak for myself but that would take some tinkering time. Your manipulation/touch events are going to be tied to the object initiating them. Your scenario in my mind would require some collision detection basically. Or....if they're of fixed size it would be much easier to have logic like if manipulation > width(or height) of object then sibling changes it's color, which you could pass to whatever is beside or above/below based on whether it's an X or Y direction of the manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! :D

I've used MouseEnter event on the rectangles to change the color and MouseLeave on the Grid that contains them to set it back to the original one! It works flawlessly! :D